# Retry dropped ssh connections

Tags: ssh, shell

I use `ssh -L -g`, but intermittently the connection is lost, thus:

```
$ ssh -L 8080:localhost:8080 example.com -g
Last login: Tue Apr 24 07:19:04 2012 from 203.0.113.123
Read from remote host example.com: Connection timed out
Connection to example.com closed.
```

Can anyone suggest a robust way to keep these connections alive, and reconnect it they are closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`autossh`](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/) appears to fulfill my requirement, from the [readme](http://www.harding.motd.ca/autossh/README):

```
autossh is a program to start a copy of ssh and monitor it, 
restarting it as necessary should it die or stop passing traffic.
```

Substituting the arguments given in the question:

```
autossh -M 0 -L 8080:localhost:8080 example.com -g
```

(the `-M 0` is required to turn the `monitoring loop off`)

I was able to `kill -9` the connection from `example.com` and see the connection re-established automatically by `autossh`:

```
local$ autossh -M 0 -L 8080:localhost:8080 example.com -g
Last login: Wed Apr 25 03:23:56 2012 from 203.0.113.123
example.com$
```

Execute `kill -9` on PID of connection on `example.com`.

```
local$ Connection to example.com closed.
Last login: Wed Apr 25 03:34:01 2012 from 203.0.113.123
local$
```

Answer (score 8):

You could try [Mosh](http://mosh.mit.edu/).

Comment: Damn, that looks awesome, I work on the train every day and I can't believe I never thought to look for a general solution to the problem. As you can probably see, I actually found `autossh` which _appears_ to solve the specific problem I have, but I'll definitely check Mosh out.

Comment: mosh doesn't handle port forwarding